# Issue with callback function

Tags: jquery

the following site works fine, however when I click on the navigation tabs to fade in and out the relative content the footer fades in and out too and I don't want that to happen.

Link to the working site: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/Pilates/Pilates/HTML/

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    var
        home = $('.home'),
        classes = $('.classes'),
        contacts = $('.contacts'),
        home_tab = $('.home_tab'),
        classes_tab = $('.classes_tab'),
        contacts_tab = $('.contacts_tab'),
        h_c = home.add(contacts),
        h_cl = home.add(classes),
        c_cl = contacts.add(classes),
        fast = 1200;


    home.css('display', 'block'); // display the home section on page load to start with

    classes.css('display', 'none');
    contacts.css('display', 'none');

    classes_tab.click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        h_c.fadeOut(fast, function(){
        classes.fadeIn(fast);
        });
    });

    contacts_tab.click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault(evt);
        h_cl.fadeOut(fast, function(){
            contacts.fadeIn(fast);
        });
    });

    home_tab.click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        c_cl.fadeOut(fast, function(){
            home.fadeIn(fast);
        });
    });



});
```

All this is happening between the header and the footer, maybe there is something wrong in my jQuery

Comment: You'll need to show the (relevant) HTML as well.

Comment: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/Pilates/Pilates/HTML/

Comment: It looks as though your footer is just flicking down and back up rather than fading in/out

Comment: hard to see what happens in the footer. My screen is not big enough.

Comment: @AlexRichards yes that's what happening, but I don't want that to happen it's just the content area with text is that needs to fade out and in, the footer needs to stay where it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer doesn't fade. It gets pushed down below our view because both content divs (the one fading out, and the one fading in) are visible during the animation.

what you should do is only fade in the new content once the old content is completely gone.

your flaw is using h_cl, which fires the callback quickly because you are hiding already hidden elements.

try this:

```
h_cl.filter(':visible').fadeOut(...
```

this will make sure you are fading only the visible elements, which will only fire the callback once it really is gone.

Comment: but does the call back suppose to make one action finish bwfore starting the other one?

Comment: OK fine it's clear now, I didn't realize that (as you said) I was hiding something that was already hidden, would there be a better way of doing this?

Comment: it's commonly accepted to give an "active" or "selected" class to the currently visible element and then using that class to select in your fades. this way you use: $('.contentDiv.selected').fadeOut(...

Comment: you just make sure to move that selected class to the new div whenever one is faded in